# Kivy showing a black screen when trying to use kv file?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

So I want to do the styling of my Kivy app in a external .kv file, but when I run the main code, nothing appears to the black Kivy window.

Here's my main file called main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass
    
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And here's the .kv file located in the same directory and called my.kv

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<MyGrid>:
    Label:
        text: "example example"
```

So I'm not getting any error, just nothing appearing in the Kivy GUI when I run the main code.

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: Try to name this kivy file `my.kv`. I named something else and it was showing black screen for me too. So I renamed it my.kv and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load widgets from a separate kivy file, you need to import `Builder`:

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
Builder.load_file('my.kv')
```

or in **.py** file

```
Builder.load_string("""
<MyGrid>:
    Label:
        text: "example example"
""")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working fine. Still would like to have the autoload working but I have no clue how that works.

Answer (score 1):

The kivy file name should always be the App class name, in your case you should save file with **MyApp.kv**
else you need to use Builder to import

Comment: The "App" piece is optional for the file name.